# CSS, outline-offset: setting the offset for each side individually

Tags: html, css, outline

In CSS using a `outline`. Can I set the outline-offset for each side individually?

I don't want to add padding (or any other content) to my element.

Here is a visual representation of what I mean:

[image]

Looked all over MDN but couldn't find anything. Is this possible?

Comment: You may use `border` or `box-shadow` instead, which has those options.

Comment: Okay so this is not possible?

Comment: No, using outline isn't possible to set different values.

Comment: Otherwise I will update my code to have a border instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pseudo element and you can easily control space and size using border:

```css
.outline {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  margin:20px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.outline:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-10px;
  right:-20px;
  top:-5px;
  bottom:-5px;
  border:2px solid;
  border-right-width:4px;
  border-left-width:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline">
  Content
</div>
```